# Mocking Passport authentication on protected endpoints

Tags: express, mongoose, continuous-integration, mocha.js, passport.js

I'm using passport local strategy to authenticate users and I'm having issues with continuous integration testing on protected endpoints. I used [this tutorial](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/) to get my authentication up and running. I'm using mocha/chai for testing and I can't figure out how to test an endpoint with a user logged during testing. I understand that I may have to use a mock strategy but I'm not sure how to do that. Here is an example endpoint, I need the user to be logged in so that I have access to the req.user.id variable that gets set when I a user is logged in.

```
router.post('/user/draft/delete', (req, res) => {
if(!req.user) {
    return res.redirect('/login');
}

User
    .findById(req.user.id)
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
        user.drafts.pull(req.body.draftid);
        user.save();
        res.status(202).redirect('/dashboard');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).redirect('/dashboard');
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what other information might be required but I'm happy to update this post with any code needed.